# How to work left outer join in SQl Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, outer-join

First: I know to use all types of join but **I don't know why it works like this for this Query**

I have a Scenario for making a SQL Query, by using 3 tables and a left outer join between selling and order items.

**My Tables**:

```
--------------------
   Item 
--------------------
ID      |  Code
--------------------
1       |  7502

SQL > select * from Item where id = 1
---------------------

   Item_Order
---------------------------
Item   |  Box   |   Quantity
---------------------------
1      | 30     |  15000
1      | 12     |  6000
SQL > select * from Item_Order where Item = 1
--------------------------

   Invoice_Item
-------------------
Item  |  Num  |  Quantity
-------------------------
1     | 1.64  | 10
1     | 2.4   | 8
SQL > select * from Invoice_Item where Item = 1
```

I want this output:

```
Item  | OrderQ  | OrderB | SellN | SellQ
-----------------------------------------
1     | 1500    | 30     |  1.64 | 10
1     | 6000    | 12     |  2.4  | 8
```

My SQL code:

```
SELECT  Item.ID, Item_Order.Box As OrderB, Item_Order.Quantity As OrderQ, Invoice_Item.Num As SellN, Invoice_Item.Quantity As SellQ
FROM Item LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Invoice_Item ON Item.ID = Invoice_Item.Item LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Item_Order ON Item_Order.Item = Item.ID  
where Item.ID = 1
```

[image: Out put My Code]

Why is my output 2x? or why does my output return 4 records?

Comment: Your output is doubled because you didn't provide enough relationship between your orders and your invoices.  How is SQL supposed to know which invoice goes with which order?

Comment: To write queries correctly, one needs to understand your schema. To do that, we need to understand what the relationships are between the tables you have - those are enforced with constraints. Show DDL. Next, we need to understand your goal. A query that "doesn't work" is not very useful if we don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @SMor can i return 2 record for this case by change sql query ?

Comment: This isn't really an outer join question. The first join results in two rows. For each of those rows the second join creates two more.

Comment: @SMor Constraints, including FKs--"relationships [sic] between the tables"--are not needed to query. Table meanings are sufficient & necessary. A (base or result) query represents a relation(ship)/association. When constraints hold, some expressions become equivalent to queries that are correct independent of constraints. We do need to know constraints to address a query expression that relied on them.

Comment: Clearly it is not the case that you "know [how] to use all types of join", *because* you "don't know why it works like this for this Query".  "Why" you get your results is because that's how SQL works. If you want to know why you don't get what you expect, you have to tell us what you expect & why you expect it so we can tell you where you are wrong. Also: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS Don't expect us to guess from an example. Say how output is a function of base tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result can be achieve with `row_number`:

```
select a.ID
       , a.OrderB
       , a.OrderQ
       , b.Quantity SellQ
       , b.Num SellN
from 
(SELECT Item.ID
       , Item_Order.Box As OrderB
       , Item_Order.Quantity As OrderQ
       , row_number () over (order by Item.ID) rn
FROM Item 
left outer JOIN Item_Order ON Item.ID = Item_Order.Item) a
left outer join (select Item
                        , Num
                        , Quantity
                        , row_number () over (order by Item) rn 
                 from Invoice_Item ) b
on a.ID = b.Item
and a.rn = b.rn
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1de9f9b61e6092387dc3e5b4bacc61a5)

You can add more tables like this:

```
left outer join (select Item
                            , Num
                            , Quantity
                            , row_number () over (order by Item) rn 
                     from Invoice_Item ) b
```

Comment: Your sql code work thanks but can you explain ? An what happened if add table itemTrash like itemOrder design ?

Comment: With row_number you add one more column you can use to join and in that way you remove the duplicates. Do check how row_number works. For the second part of your question : "An what happened if add table itemTrash like itemOrder design ?" - I do not understand you.... Please explain

Comment: for second question, i want join new Table neme “itemTrash columns item, qnt” how to joint your query ?

Comment: I believe I have added answer to your question . Please check my updated answer. You can add more tables like that. The same way I have added Invoice_Item  table. Also you can add table Item_Order  like that. this is just one way to do it and every new table can be added in a style I have added the table Invoice_Item . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is duplicating because you have no secondary association between Invoice_Item and Item_Order.  For each record in Invoice_Item it is matching to Item_Order (known as a Cartesian result) base ONLY on the Item ID.  So, your order qty APPEARS to be a 1:1 reference such that the first Invoice item Qty of 10 is MEANT to be associated with Item_Order Box = 30.  and Qty 8 is MEANT to be associated with Item_Order Box = 12.

```
Item_Order
Item   Box   Quantity
1      30    15000
1      12    6000


Invoice_Item
Item  Num    Quantity
1     1.64   10
1     2.4    8
```

You probably need to tack on the "Box" reference so Item_Order and Invoice_Item are a 1:1 match.

What is happening is for each item in Invoice Item is joined to the Item_Order based on Item ID.  So you are getting two.  If you had 3 Invoice Items with 1 and 6 of Items_Order, you would be getting 18 rows.

**FEEDBACK**

Even though you have an accepted answer based on an OVER/PARTITION/ROW NUMBER, that process is forcing a surrogate secondary ID to each row.  Relying on this approach is not best for an overall data structure association.  What happens if you delete the second item on an order.  are you positive you are deleting the second item in the invoice_items?

As for returning 2 records in the original scenario, you can via the surrogate process, but I think it would be better for you long term to understand what is happening on the join.  Going back to your sample data of Item_Order and Invoice_Item.  So lets start with the Item_Order table.  The SQL engine is going to process each row individually.

First row SQL grabs Item = 1, Box = 30, Qty = 15000.

So now it joins to the Invoice Item table, and since your criteria it only joins based on Item.  So, it sees the first row and says... yup this is item 1, so include that with the item order record (first row returned).  Now it goes to the second line in the invoice item table... yup, it too is the same item 1, so it returns it again (second row returned).

Now, SQL grabs the second row Item = 1, Box = 12, Qty = 6000.

Goes back to the Invoice Item table and does exact same test... and for each row in the Item Order that has an Item = 1, and 3rd and 4th row hence your doubling...  If either table had more records with the same Item id, it would return that many more records... 3 and 3 records would have returned 9 rows.  4 and 4 records would return 16 rows, etc.  Doing the surrogate will work, but I don't think as safe as a better/updated design structure.

Comment: you mean can't never return 2 record for this case ?

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed, added clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you first join `Item` with `Item_Order` it outputs two records because there are two records in `Item_Order`. Now this resulting query will be left join with `Invoice_Item` and that two records will be join with all of the records of `Invoice_Item`

You can better understand this like this

```
SELECT  Item.ID, Item_Order.Box As OrderB, Item_Order.Quantity As OrderQ, Invoice_Item.Num As SellN, Invoice_Item.Quantity As SellQ
FROM Item LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Invoice_Item ON Item.ID = Invoice_Item.Item LEFT OUTER JOIN 
where Item.ID = 1 into table4 //Only to explain
```

Now the result of first query `table4` will be joined with `Items_Order`

Answer (score 0):

You are joining on one key -- two rows with the same key in one table times two rows in the second table = 4 rows.

You need a separate key.  You can generate one using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT i.ID, io.Box As OrderB, io.Quantity As OrderQ,
       ii.Num As SellN, ii.Quantity As SellQ
FROM Item i LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     ((SELECT ii.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ii.item ORDER BY ii.item) as seqnum
       FROM Invoice_Item ii
      ) FULL JOIN
      (SELECT io.*, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY io.item ORDER BY io.item) as seqnum
       FROM Item_Order io
      ) io
      ON io.Item = ii.ID AND io.seqnum = ii.seqnum
     )
     ON i. = ii.Item 
where i.ID = 1;
```

Note that this is one of the few cases where I use parentheses in the `FROM` clause.  This code can handle additional rows in *either* of the tables -- if one table is longer than the other, the columns from the other will be `NULL`.

If you know the two tables have the same number of rows (for a given item) you can just use inner joins and no parentheses.